# How to handle imperfections in transfering thousands of files using Jsch?

Tags: java, scp, jsch

I have written and tested Java code that uses Jsch to transfer files.  The transfer from the source computer, HERE, to a destination computer, THERE, works flawlessly.  Using the same unmodified code, the transfer from HERE to another computer, PROBLEM, works about half the time.  The problem being that the code will, on random file, hang on the write or close, and there are no exceptions thrown, even after a extremely long timeout.  (After the next use of the channel after the extremely long timeout causes an exception.) Using the linux command "scp" (openssh-clients) works flawlessly copying the same set of files, both from HERE to THERE and HERE to PROBLEM.

I assume there is an imperfection in the transmission or reception of the files that openssh::scp has been designed to detect and work around.  Any suggestions as to how to 
proceed.

Detail(s):

1. methods used for write/close

   ```
   OutputStream fos = put(String rp3);
   fos.close();
   ```
2. Is there a means similar to unix alarm/SIGALRM to interrupt the write/close so that
   the attempt can be retried?
3. Is there a session setConfig parameter that instructs Jsch to be more fault tolerant?  Where are these documented?
4. Should I switch to another Java implementation of scp?

Comment: Have you checked JSCh examples ? Also using the latest version may help.